# Problem with intuition regarding continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, intuition

Suppose we have as a topological space $X$ the  figure eight space. Let $A \subset X$ be one of the circles, then evidently one has a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow A$ by mapping the other circle to the point of intersection. Often, when I visualize continuous functions, I consider them as if they are "deformations" of the space (I do NOT mean the real topological notion of 'deformation', but the one you find in the dictionary).

However, this has some complications: for this to make sense (as highlighted by my example) I would always need some ambient space in which I can visualise this deformation. In my case, this is evident: just use the Euclidean space, then the 'continuous deformation' is the one collapsing the circle to said point.

However, I don't feel comfortable with just embedding everything into the Euclidean space, or some other bigger ambient topological space. My question is then: is this intuition bad? If yes, what is a better intuition to know if a map is 'continuous'? (I mean this broadly, I know that we can't always embed it into an Euclidean space, but this doesn't take away the fact that I can look at continuous maps as 'deformations' of the topological space)

Comment: I'm not a topology expert, but I think it is fine to have simple mental models (such as visualizations that are embedded in Euclidean space) as far as intuition is concerned. The important thing is whether you can fluently move between intuition and rigorous definitions so that you are not totally helpless as soon as you come across a more complicated situation.

Comment: Here are some observations that may help. Any set-theoretic mapping $f : X \to Y$ decomposes as a composite $h \circ g$, where $g$ is a surjection $X \to \mathsf{ran}(f)$ and $h$ is the injection of $\mathsf{ran}(f)$ into $Y$. I.e., $f$ works by "crumpling up" some subsets so that they map to a single point and then "adding on" some extra points. If $X$ and $Y$ are equipped with a topologies, $h$ is automatically continuous w.r.t the subspace topology on $\mathsf{ran}(f)$ and you only have to worry about whether the "crumpling" is compatible with the topologies on $X$ and $\mathsf{ran}(f)$.

Comment: Your intuition is alright, but question: why do you need to embed it in Euclidean space? Take that same picture, but throw out the background. The extra loop "shrinks" to a point not by moving through some other space, but just ... does. Now you are looking at just what happens to the space itself instead of adding unnecessary details. Then you notice that nothing really changes until the very end when you switch from loop to point. Until then, it is still the same two-loop space it always was. At the end is where things are interesting.

Answer (score -2):

Topology is not about form, geometry is about form, topology is a way to deform the properties of the space, not the space itself, at least in my point of view.

Comment: To give a little help for you, try to undestand that a torus for a topologist is nothing more then a coffe cup, the form just does not matter at all.

Comment: I've should have said thats my opinion and nothing else, sorry.